# How to hide logo in product page in Open Cart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I need to hide logo in product page. Logo is placed in header HTML.

So, I tried to add new variable `$data['product_page_logo']` in `header.php` controller before loading template like as:

$data['product_page_logo'] = false;

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl')) {
    return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
} else {
    return $this->load->view('default/template/common/header.tpl', $data);
}
```

After in `header.tpl` I check this variable:

```
<? if(isset($data['product_page_logo']) && $data['product_page_logo'] == false) {
    echo "Logo";
}?>
```

But it does not work, I get error undefined variable `product_page_logo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `route`, in `catalog/controller/common/header.php` find:

```
$class = '-' . $this->request->get['product_id'];
```

before or after it add:

```
$data['logo'] = '';
```

tested on opencart 2.3.0.2

Comment: Can I check this in template? And in what controller?

Comment: In bottom of file `product.php` there is `$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');`. Seems it overwrites all properties was set above

Comment: Hello, in catalog/controller/common/header.php